# How to add an additional action to a button on a modal component in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal component that has a button with `data-dismiss="modal"`. I also need to bind another action when clicking this button. I tried:

```
$("#lsfModal").on("click", ".btn-ok", function(){
    window.location = someURL;
});
```

I also tried with `mousedown` instead of `click` but with no luck. I noticed that this function isn't called at all.

Any ideas? Thanks

The html I'm using:

```
<div class="modal" id="lsfModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lsfModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="lsfModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**LATER EDIT**: Damn it. I was actually using a different selector: `$("#lsfModal.confirm")` . The class `confirm` was added later via javascript so that's why it was not working. :|

Comment: Please show us all your HTML

Comment: What is other event other than this?

Comment: The other event is the the closing of the modal.

Comment: Yep use @Ravi's answer since I believe you are quite possibly only having the Modal added after document load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are adding model runtime. you need to use the delegation for this purpose.

```
$("body").on("click", "#lsfModal.btn-ok", function(){
   // do some thing herer
});
```

Markup..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
         <button type="button " class="btn btn-primary deleteButton" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Delete</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteButton", function(){
       // do some thing herer
  alert('sds');
    });
```

You can play with bootply [BootstrapDialog](http://www.bootply.com/Gs4OKnxKd8)

Comment: +1 You *could* very well be correct but without more code in the question we can't be sure!

Comment: Damn it. I was actually using a different selector: `$("#lsfModal.confirm")` . The class `confirm` was added later via javascript so that's why it was not working. :|

Answer (score 0):

if u want to attach a handler to dynamically generated controls please use delegate syntax

```
$( "container" ).on( "click", "#urcontrol", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: This adds no value over the previously added answer by Ravi